# Comparing similar images as photographs -- detecting difference, image diff

Tags: image-processing, language-agnostic, computer-vision

The situation is kind of unique from anything I have been able to find asked already, and is as follows: *If I took a photo of two similar images, I'd like to be able to highlight the differing features in the two images.* For example the following two halves of a children's spot the difference game:

[image: left half of spot the difference] [image: right half of spot the difference]

The differences in the images will be bits missing/added and/or colour change, and the type of differences which would be easily detectable from the original image files by doing nothing cleverer than a pixel-by-pixel comparison. However the fact that they're subject to the fluctuations of light and imprecision of photography, I'll need a far more lenient/clever algorithm.

As you can see, the images won't necessarily line up perfectly if overlaid.

This question is tagged language-agnostic as I expect answers that point me towards relevant algorithms, however I'd also be interested in current implementations if they exist, particularly in Java, Ruby, or C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following approach should work. All of these functionalities are available in OpenCV. Take a look at [this example](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/revisions/master/raw/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/features2D/SURF_Homography.cpp) for computing homographies.

- Detect keypoints in the two images using a corner detector.
- Extract descriptors (SIFT/SURF) for the keypoints.
- Match the keypoints and compute a homography using RANSAC, that aligns the second image to the first.
- Apply the homography to the second image, so that it is aligned with the first.
- Now simply compute the pixel-wise difference between the two images, and the difference image will highlight everything that has changed from the first to the second.

Comment: Great clear answer, I will have a go at implementing something in OpenCV this evening.

Comment: beware that an homography is almost rigid : it maps a plane (in 3d) to a plane (it does not take deformations into account). In your example above, it would result in a simple global translation to the right. Homographies are used to compensate for camera motion when the camera is looking at a planar surface.

Comment: Yup I second that. In the current example, it looks like you're matching a planar object (the painting), so it should be alright to use homographies. But if you apply this method to real 3D objects, the homography will be computed with the assumption that all features lie on the same plane, which in turn may give you an unexpected alignment of images.

Comment: Indeed, for that application it might be enough. The best way is to try it out and judge, and it is anyway easier to implement than my solution - so it's indeed a good start.

Comment: Struggling to figure out how to extract SIFT descriptors for the points discovered with Harris corner detector (in OpenCV), hmpf..

Comment: In the example above, try replacing "SurfDescriptorExtractor" with "SiftDescriptorExtractor". It should work straight away I think.

Answer (score 4):

My general approach would be to use an optical flow to align both images and perform a pixel by pixel comparison once they are aligned.

However, for the specifics, standard optical flows (OpenCV etc.) are likely to fail if the two images differ significantly like in your case. If that indeed fails, there are recent optical flow techniques that are supposed to work even if the images are drastically different. For instance, you might want to look at the paper about [SIFT flows by Ce Liu et al](http://people.csail.mit.edu/celiu/SIFTflow/SIFTflow.pdf) that addresses this problem with sparse correspondences.